# C# List merging without repeating

Tags: c#, list, merge

My question is at the end of the following code in comments:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class MyObj
{
    int m_id;

    public MyObj(int id)
    {
        this.m_id = id;
    }

    public int GetId()
    {
        return this.m_id;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m0 = new MyObj(0);
        var m1 = new MyObj(1);
        var m2 = new MyObj(2);
        var m3 = new MyObj(3);
        var m4 = new MyObj(4);


        List<MyObj> refList1 = new List<MyObj>()
            {
                m0, m1, m2, m3
            };

        List<MyObj> refList2 = new List<MyObj>()
            {
                m1, m2, m3, m4
            };


        //How to merge refList2 into refList1 without id repeating,
        //so refList1 must be [m0, m1, m2, m3, m4]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do this using LINQ, with:

```
var resultList = refList1.Union(refList2).ToList();
```

However, this requires either that `MyObj` implements `IEquatable<MyObj>`, or the other overload of `Union` is used which takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` parameter.

The first solution would need this change:

```
class MyObj : IEquatable<MyObj>
{
    int m_id;

    public MyObj(int id)
    {
        this.m_id = id;
    }

    public int GetId()
    {
        return this.m_id;
    }

    public bool Equals(MyObj other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) {
            return true;
        }
        return other.m_id == this.m_id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(MyObj)) {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((MyObj)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.m_id;
    }
}
```

The second solution would go like:

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObj>
{
    public bool Equals(MyObj x, MyObj y)
    {
        return x.GetId() == y.GetId();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObj obj)
    {
        return obj.GetId();
    }
}

var resultList = refList1.Union(refList2, new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

and would not require changes to `class MyObj`.

Comment: @Edward83: If it makes sense to have a **single** definition of equality for `MyObj` objects across your application, and you can edit the source code, the first approach might be preferable (and it will let you reuse the equality logic for free anywhere). Otherwise, go with the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Union`

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Union Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx).

```
var merged = refList2.Union(refList1).ToList();
```

And define the Equals/Hashcode methods.  Once you do this it will automatically remove the duplicates.

```
class MyObj{
     /*your stuff*/

     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {        
        var r_list= obj as MyObj;
        if(r_list == null) return false;
        return this._m_id==r_list.m_id;
     }

     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
        return m_id;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
refList1 = refList1.Union(refList2).Distinct.ToList();
```